# Please how to complete such a button style through CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS style for a button. I don’t know how to do it. I think it’s a bit too complicated and it’s not easy to make responsive adjustments. I would like to ask everyone how to write a button like this in CSS? thanks

[image]

```css
.save_coin {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.save_coin::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 32px;
  padding: 26px 101px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .save_coin::after {
    border-radius: 38px;
    padding: 38px 102px;
  }
}
.save_coin span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 192px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .save_coin span {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 15px 46px;
  }
}
.save_coin:hover span {
  color: #222;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="save_coin"><span>ｓａｖｅ</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `outline` attribute, work pretty good imo.

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button>save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what I have seen my simple and clean way of writing

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `box-shadow` CSS property:

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  
  /*  outer line */
  border: 5px solid black;
  
  /* some very large number, to get a pill effect */
  border-radius: 1024px;
  padding: 30px 60px 30px 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  
  /*  inner white line */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px white;
  
  /* custom transition */
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* ignore this if you just want button design */
button:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">立即儲值</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, let me see different ways of writing